# I just cannot install Mongodb in my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb

First I used the documentation of Ubuntu.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Step1:  After that I ran commands according to documentation.

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

I got the following result:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

OK

After that I used the command to upgrade and update everything.

After that I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I got error:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Wonder why they didn't migrate this to Ubuntu but try these commands basically `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install libssl1.1`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403619/mongodb-install-fails-on-ubuntu-22-04-depends-on-libssl1-1-but-it-is-not-insta

Answer (score 0):

Check out this writeup by priamcse, it solved this issue for me.

https://www.junktheme.com/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-mongodb-installation-ubuntu-22-04/

I first had to install curl with the following command:

```
sudo snap install curl  # version 7.86.0
```

After, I referred to his page by executing the following cmds:

Install libSSL

```
curl -LO http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i ./libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb
```

Install Mongodb

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb-org
```

Check version

```
mongod -version
```

Let me know if it fixes your issues.